# Monochrome vs. Monochromatic

Tags: differences, terminology

What is the usage difference for the words monochrome (as an adjective) and monochromatic? Various dictionaries seem to have nearly identical definitions for the two words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Monochrome* refers to things, such as drawings, pictures, and photographs, that are in shades of one (or a very limited number) of colors.

*Monochromatic* can also be used to refer to the above, but is used exclusively to describe monochromatic light, which is light of a narrow wavelength band.

Ironically, a monochrome drawing would not reflect monochromatic light under a spectrograph (because white light is a broad spectrum), while a rainbow picture would, in fact, reflect monochromatic light (in the local sense) because each color of the rainbow is a narrow spectrum.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochrome